# How to call CSS class directly without full hierarchy?

Tags: css

I have CSS class in use that has path

.override .sidebar label.firstheading

I'm trying to create style guide and use the same class in it as showcase, but style guide doesn't have sidebar element. Can I call ".override .sidebar label.firstheading" directly in class="" without full hierarchy?

If I add .sidebar element leading to it in style guide, it gets so much formatting from .sidebar that it messes the whole page up.

Comment: can you post some example code?

Comment: You can't put `class="override sidebar label.firstheading"` to work with selector `.override .sidebar label.firstheading`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styling should always be as less specific as possible! You should have a basic styling for `label` specialized `label.firstheading` and if the structure is important for the label you should add more specifity (`.sidebar label {}` and/or `.sidebar label.firstheading {...}`).

If you follow this scheme you will be able to override styles and to use your html more modular.

In other words: you should reorganize the styling for the `label.firstheading` component